# Buffer overflow vulnerability

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 int check_authentication(char *password) 
{
 int auth_flag = 0;
 char password_buffer[16];
 strcpy(password_buffer, password);
 if(strcmp(password_buffer, "unipi") == 0)
    auth_flag = 1;
 if(strcmp(password_buffer, "SSL") == 0)
    auth_flag = 1;
 return auth_flag;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
 }
 if(check_authentication(argv[1])!=0)
 {
    printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
    printf(" Access Granted.\n");
    printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
 }
 else
 {
     printf("\nAccess Denied.\n");
 }
}
```

At line  `strcpy(password_buffer, password);`it has a buffer overflow vulnerability. If we want to make this program secure without taking out the `strcpy` , how is it possible?

Comment: The best way is to replace `strcpy` with a safe function. What are you looking to accomplish by keeping `strcpy`?

Comment: *"If we want to make this program secure"* **Secure against what?**

Comment: `char password_buffer[strlen(password)+1]`. Welcome to *stack overflow*.

Comment: Why are you copying `password` at all?

Comment: @Micheal This is out of the scope of this question. I just wanted to try to make it secure without removing the `strcpy`

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Not been vulnerable to buffer overflow attacks cause of the `strcpy`.....

Comment: @Schwern Out of the scope of this question

Comment: @J.S The question "what are you looking to accomplish by keeping strcpy" has not been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. 
You change the verification that the user input is as expected else where.
With strlen so that you can check that the string is shorter than 16 bytes.

```
if(strlen(argv[1]) > 15)
{
    printf("too long password\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This check should probably be done inside the `check_authentication()` function.

Comment: No you should have it in the main function before the call so to not waste resources.

Comment: Waste what resources?

Comment: Definitely do it inside the `check_authentication()` function because A) that's the function which controls the size of the password buffer and B) then you don't have to [forget to] put this check everywhere `check_authentication()` is called.

Comment: Schwern i agree with you, but this example which is taken hacking the art of exploitation by John Erickson hopefully isn't going to be used in the real world. And as it is now having the check in main saves the resources used to build a stack frame

Comment: Saving the resources to build a stack frame is not a concern for this example.  It's of more value to teach where the proper place for parameter validation is than to teach about worrying about the resources used to build a stack frame (which is negligible in nearly all cases other than maybe for the tightest of loops). Except for unbounded recursion, the creation of a stack frame is probably one of the lowest priority things to be concerned with in programming.

Comment: @StormKavlie It looks like this is a homework question, which is why I wanted clarification from OP on why he wanted to keep `strcpy` when in the real world the fix is to use a safe function. OP ignored that question altogether when I asked why he wanted to keep `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this on Wiki:

> To prevent the buffer overflow from happening in this example, the
>   call to strcpy could be replaced with strncpy, which takes the maximum
>   capacity of A as an additional parameter and ensures that no more than
>   this amount of data is written to A:
>
> ```
> strncpy(password_buffer, password, sizeof(A));
> ```
>
> Note that the above code is not free from problems either; while a
>   buffer overrun has been prevented this time, the strncpy library
>   function does not null-terminate the destination buffer if the source
>   string's length is greater than or equal to the size of the buffer
>   (the third argument passed to the function), therefore A is, in this
>   case, not null-terminated and cannot be treated as a valid C-style
>   string.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to deal with this.

---

First, and perhaps most important, is to ***avoid fixed memory allocations*** especially when dealing with input.  In your example above instead of copying to a fixed size buffer you can make the buffer the size you need.

```
char password_copy[strlen(password) + 1];
strcpy(password_copy, password);
```

But that's not always possible.  Maybe you've got already allocated memory.  Maybe you do want to truncate the input (though [16 is far too small for a password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Guidelines_for_strong_passwords)).

---

One is to not use the C string handling functions at all, they're riddled with flaws and security holes.  Instead use a library like Gnome Lib which features [the G_String type](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Strings.html#GString). G_Strings track their length and allocated size.  This takes a little more memory, but it's faster.  Finding the length of the string, something that happens a lot, doesn't require iterating through every byte of the string.

[G_Strings have their own set of string handling functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Strings.html#GString) which are much handier than the C ones.  It also can grow strings as necessary or allocate new strings for you.

```
/* Allocate memory for the copy and copy the password */
G_String *password_copy = g_string_new(password);
```

For compatibility with regular string functions `password_copy->str` returns a normal `char *`.

This is IMO the best way.  You no longer have to remember to check string lengths and allocated sizes and worry about null bytes everywhere you use strings.  You will forget.  Let the computer do that.

---

If you must use C standard functions, don't use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) because it fails to guarantee the truncated string will be null terminated.  Instead use [`strlcpy`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strlcpy).  It's like `strncpy` but it guarantees the copied string will be null terminated. `strlcpy` is a BSD extension, so it's not guaranteed to be portable.  [glibc refuses to implement it](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FAQ#Why_no_strlcpy_.2BAC8_strlcat.3F).

For maximum portability, efficiency, and safety use `strlcpy` and provide a fallback using `memmove` and `#ifndef strlcpy` so it will only be used if `strlcpy` is not already available.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef strlcpy
size_t strlcpy(char * restrict dst, const char * restrict src, size_t dst_size) {
    /* size is the allocated size. len leaves space for the null byte */
    size_t dst_len = dst_size - 1;
    size_t src_len = strlen(src);

    /* Use the smaller of the two string lengths to avoid buffer overflow */
    size_t move_len = src_len > dst_len ? dst_len : src_len;

    /* Copy the string, truncate if necessary. It will work
     * even if src and dst overlap. */
    memmove(dst, src, move_len);

    /* Guarantee there's a null byte */
    dst[move_len] = '\0';

    /* strlcpy returns the size of the string it tried to make.
     * This is used to detect truncation. */
    return src_len;
}
#endif

int main()
{
    char dst[10];
    char *src = "12345678901234567890";

    printf("%zu\n", strlcpy(dst, src, 10));
    printf("src: %s, dst: %s\n", src, dst);

    return 0;
}
```